# I can't view vb 2013 in vb 2010

Tags: vb.net

I opened visual studio 2013 file in visual studio 2010 and I can't edit the design view and says it has an error. What should I do?

[image]

Comment: The newest .NET Framework possible for Visual Basic 2010 is actually 4.0. You cannot target 4.5 in the 2010 versions.

Comment: Ah!  I skipped 2010.  So, find whatever is referencing a 4.5 assembly and change it or remove that component/control/doodad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target framework for the project is higher then what Visual Basic 2010 supports. You will need to change it to v4.0 in project properties or manually in the manifest file, but you might be just better off getting Visual Studio 2015 which supports all the frameworks.

Comment: where can I find in the project properties the version wherein I can change it to v4.0?

Comment: @G.Sandoval Sorry for the late reply, I was coding a huge update. Look on the menu strip, click on the drop down for Project. From there click Properties. Change the Target Framework to .NET Framework 4 Client Profile or .NET Framework 3.5 Client Profile which is more universal.